# Angularjs - Dynamic Name for input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem should be quite simple.
I have an input inside a ng-repeat where the name is inserted dynamically and then I want to validate the input from the form using:

```
{{myForm.{{entry.dynamicField}}.$invalid}} //ERROR Token '{' is not a valid identifier
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <tr ng-repeat="entry in array">
    <td>
      <input name="{{entry.dynamicName}}" />
      <span ng-show="myForm.{{entry.dynamicName}}.$invalid">Invalid</span> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `ng-model` in order to bind your dynamic data into the `input` element. And, get rid of angular expression in `ng-show`.

This should be changed

```
ng-show="myForm.{{entry.dynamicName}}.$invalid"
```

to

```
ng-show="myForm.entry.dynamicName.$invalid"
```

**Snippet**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [{
    dynamicName: "John Doe"
  }, {
    dynamicName: "John Doe2"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="entry in array">
        <td>
          <input name="entry.dynamicName" ng-model="entry.dynamicName" />
          <span ng-show="myForm.entry.dynamicName.$invalid">Invalid</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt work... you are just putting name as entry.dynamicName

Comment: @TiagoSilva That is not the problem. You forgot to add `<table>` element. I edited my answer to reflect that piece so that it displays correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty same as in JS:

```
{{myForm[entry.dynamicField].$invalid}}
```

And just remember - you always use {{}} only once for expression.